# Scheme function won't print

Tags: scheme, sicp

Please tell me why the following Scheme function won't print the result. I'm using DrRacket.

```
#lang sicp

(define (sqr x) (* x x))

(define (sum_of_greatest_squares a b c)
  (if(> a b)
       (if(> a c)
             (if(> b c)
                  ((+ (sqr a) (sqr c))(+ (sqr a) (sqr b))))
             (+ (sqr a) (sqr c))
        )
       (if(> b c)
            (if (> a c)
                  ((+ (sqr a) (sqr b))(+ (sqr b) (sqr c)))
            (+ (sqr c) (sqr b))))
       ))
(sum_of_greatest_squares 3 4 5)
```

Comment: You are not printing anything anywhere.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its plain to see that you haven't been very detail-oriented with your learning. Your code contains countless mistakes and you've allowed yourself to bring habits from other languages into your learning of scheme. DrRacket clearly shows there's a syntax error with your program, so that's a good place to start.

The sections I have bolded are missing an `else` expression

```
(define (sum_of_greatest_squares a b c)
  (if(> a b)
       (if(> a c)
             (if(> b c)
                  ((+ (sqr a) (sqr c))(+ (sqr a) (sqr b))))
             (+ (sqr a) (sqr c))
        )
       (if(> b c)
            (if (> a c)
                  ((+ (sqr a) (sqr b))(+ (sqr b) (sqr c)))
            (+ (sqr c) (sqr b))))
       ))
```

The formatting of your code is bad and thus makes it harder to see where mistakes were made.

Moving along, here's another big mistake

```
((+ (sqr a) (sqr c))(+ (sqr a) (sqr b)))
```

You can't just put `()` wherever you want, like you can in some languages. `()` are used for procedure application in Lisp/Scheme/Racket.

Say `a = 1`, `b = 2`, and `c = 3`, the above line would be the equivalent of

```
((+ (sqr 1) (sqr 3))(+ (sqr 1) (sqr 2)))
((+ 1       9      )(+ 1       4      ))
(10                                   5)
```

The last line is `(10 5)` which says "apply the number 5 to the number 10" – which makes no sense.

You make the same mistake later in the code too. Try fixing up these problems first and then update your question.

ps: don't use snake_case names like `sum_of_greatest_squares`. Schemers typically would format that as `sum-of-greatest-squares`.

---

It's not immediately clear what your procedure is supposed to do anyway. My *guess* is that it's supposed to square the two largest inputs and then sum them.

You *could* do a huge hierarchy of `if` expressions to decide which two arguments to perform a computation with... but another way would be to always use the same two arguments to compute the result, but use `if` expressions to move the appropriate arguments into the correct place.

Consider this as a lateral alternative to your procedure

```
(define (sqr x) (* x x))

(define (sum-of-greatest-squares a b c)
  (cond ((< a b) (sum-of-greatest-squares b c a))
        ((< b c) (sum-of-greatest-squares a c b))
        (else (+ (sqr a) (sqr b)))))
```

This will always sum the squares of the two greatest numbers, but does so in a much cleaner way

---

Lastly, Jörg mentions that you're not actually printing anything anywhere. I know you mean to imply that DrRacket isn't showing the result of your program in the *Interactions* window. However, if you do want to explicitly print to the console, look at the [display* and print* procedures](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html)

Comment: Thank you. It didn't work because of the brackets. This is what I was going for.   #lang sicp

(define (sqr x) (* x x))

(define (sum-of-greatest-squares a b c)
  (if(> a b)
       (if(> a c)
             (if(> b c)
                  (+ (sqr a) (sqr b))
                  (+ (sqr a) (sqr c))
                  )
             (+ (sqr a) (sqr c))
        )
       (if(> b c)
            (if (> a c)
                  (+ (sqr a) (sqr b))
                  (+ (sqr b) (sqr c)))
            (+ (sqr c) (sqr b)))
       ))

(sum-of-greatest-squares 7 8 10)

Comment: @spheroid you have three levels of comparisons while 2 is enough. If you know `a` is larger than `b` then `a` is one of the two largest. then you take the biggest of `b` and `c`. For the case where `a` is smaller than `b` you take `b` and the biggest of `a` and `c`.